# Who and where do the ETH gas fees goes to on L2 layers like Arbitrum and what is required to be a Arbitrum validator?

Tags: gas, mining, fees, arbitrum

Arbitrum gas fees are paid in ETH, but these fees do not goto ETH miners/stakers. Who do they go to exactly? If there are L2 arbitrum validators, what are the requirements to become one?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these two links:

https://developer.offchainlabs.com/arbos/l1-pricing

https://developer.offchainlabs.com/arbos/l1-to-l2-messaging

They discussed about L1 gas that goes into a L1PricerFundsPool account and L2 gas fees that are paid to miners in a vanilla L1 chain. By staking Eth into a deposit contract, anyone can become a Arbitrum validator.