# Where do arbitrum gas fees go?

Tags: gas, layer-2, arbitrum

Similar question to [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135467/who-and-where-do-the-eth-gas-fees-goes-to-on-l2-layers-like-arbitrum-and-what-is) except, based on the [arbitrum docs](https://developer.arbitrum.io/node-running/how-tos/running-a-full-node):

> ⚠️ Note: There is no protocol level incentive to run an Arbitum full node.

I know the sequencer gets paid some amount of the fee, but I thought the Arbitrum full node got paid a little as well? Does 100% of the gas fees go to the sequencer?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no fee provided to ArbOne validators; they have a bond posted and if they make an invalid fraud-proof claim they would lose that bond.

Nova validators on the other hand, receive a small portion of the L2 fees on that chain. currently 100% of all other gas fees go directly to the Arb DAO, Offchain Labs operates the only sequencer for now.